# Does cuDNN support Tesla M60?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, cudnn, tesla

As the [official website](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) for cuDNN mentioned the following:

> cuDNN is supported on Windows, Linux and MacOS systems with Pascal,
>   Kepler, Maxwell, Tegra K1 or Tegra X1 GPUs.

So Tesla M60 is not mentioned here, although it has compute capability = 5 which is > 3. So does cuDNN support Tesla M60 or not?
can I run CAFFE over it using cuDNN or not?

Comment: Tesla M60 is a Maxwell family GPU, that's what the M in M60 stands for.  Yes it is supported for cuDNN.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, cuDNN supports Tesla M60 and all Maxwell GPUs.